# How do you update the playback of an audio source which is streaming?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

http://stream.radioreklama.bg/radio1.ogg
^ let's say that's a stream. This is the initializing part:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = "http://stream.radioreklama.bg/radio1.ogg";
```

And I use this code to pause/play it (don't worry about the toggle, it works):

```
if(toggle === true) {
    audio.play();
} else {
    audio.pause();
}
```

Question is, once I pause it, the playback stays where it was paused, so my question is: how do you "update" the playback?